# installing spring security plugin to grails app failed

Tags: grails

Following the documentation

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#tutorials

it says in order to install the plugin i have to specify it in the BuildConfig file.

In BuildConfig i have the following part:

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'

        compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'

    }
```

when i run "grails compile" then i get the error

[image]

do you know what is causing this error? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you're mixing up versions - you use Grails 2.2.0 with spring security plugin for Grails 3.0

revert to version 2.0 and edit `buildconfig`, in the `plugins` section add

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5'
```

you also may need to add the following repo in the `repositories` section

```
mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
```

see http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/ for a complete documentation of the plugin on this version.

If you upgrade to Grails 3.x, you could use this version of spring security.

Comment: Thanks but i still get an error. I updated the buildconfig file but now it shows the following error:Starting process on Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC5

Comment: @user734861ok editing with the addition repo so it will resolve dependency

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. I have added the additional repo and yet i get the error "Error Failed to resolve dependencies". After adding it in buildconfig i executed "compile" in grails console.

Comment: The 2.x plugin docs are here: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I get the same error even after following the configuration from the above link.  Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information): - org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC2

Comment: It should be RC5, not RC2, and make sure it's in the `plugins` block, not dependencies

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Even after changing to RC5 from RC2 i get the same error.| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC5

Comment: @BurtBeckwith and also it is in the plugins block. I appreciate any further help!

Comment: @user734861 can you run `grails clean` and potentially even delete the `Target` directory and rerun compile

Comment: I created a new grails project. In the BuildConfig file i pasted ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5' under plugins and pasted this under repositories mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'. I then ran "grails compile" in grails console and the error i get is the same i.e  Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC5. I am very confused. I appreciate any help.